# when i am doing this way it's working but when i write the function other way why it doesn't work?

Tags: reactjs

```
    import React from 'react';

    class Login extends React.Component {
       goToDashboard(event){
         event.preventDefault();
         console.log("I am Clicked");}

    render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <h2>Login</h2>
        <form onSubmit={this.goToDashboard}>
          <label>FirstName</label>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Email" name="email" /><br />
          <label>Password</label>
          <input type="password" placeholder="password" name="password" /><br />
          <button type="submit">Login</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
export default Login;
```

when i write the function the way i declared above everything works fine but when i use arrow function instead of that it shows error why?

```
       const goToDashboard = (event) => {
         event.preventDefault();
         console.log("I am Clicked");}
```

Comment: What is the error that you get?

Comment: Wrap your goToDashboard function in another function like onClick={()=>goToDashboard}...might work what is the error you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you can't declare `const` field within a class.
If you remove `const`, it will work.

```
  goToDashboard = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("I am Clicked");
  };
```

Working demo on [CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/8xl4m7mj08).